# 406 Not acceptable error getting godaddy server

Tags: .htaccess, server, cpanel

I have face a big problem, suddenly my server response "406 Not acceptable" error.

POST not working on my server.

I tried to resolve with more scripts to fix this.

I used `.HTACCESS` script

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

But problem not solve. I can't understand other things, and I tried to contact godaddy, but there are not option to contact them, live chat is very poor, always telling that they have huge traffic.

please can you give some proper solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of error 406 error is mod_security rules on the server. Mod_security is a security module in the Apache web server that is enabled by default on all hosting accounts.

If any website, page, or any function violates one of these rules, server may send the 406 Not Acceptable error. Mostly this error triggers when you have any insecurity in your code. You could either resolve the insecurity within your code, or turn mod_security off.Turning mod_security off could open that potentially insecure page up to malicious attacks on your site. So it is better the investigate it and fix your code.

If you have WHM access check your mod security log file. It will show you exact cause what is causing this error. You may find audit logs at

```
/usr/local/apache/logs/audit_log
```

and mode security config files at

```
/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec.conf

/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec.user.conf
```